# Can't add saved credit cards to Firefox

Tags: firefox, auto-form-fill

I used `about:config` to [turn on the option to save credit card information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgBa0.png). When I go into the [Forms and Autofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRRWz.png) section, the option to save credit cards now show ups, as shown.

However, when I click the “Saved Credit Cards” the “Add” button on that [pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zVA9.png), it does nothing and I have no way to add a credit card.

---

**The “about:config” area.**

[image: The “about:config” area.]

---

**The “Forms and Autofill” options.**

[image: The “Forms and Autofill” options.]

---

**The “Saved Credit Cards” options.**

[image: The “Saved Credit Cards” options.]

Answer (score 0):

These form autofill features are currently not available to everyone and only are available in some specific distributions of the browser (US-English versions) and only for users located in U.S.

Also the release version does not have the credit card part working yet, even if you find and enable the configuration settings, feature is not included in the release version.